# image magic resize image with sample command and get quality

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick

I has a tif image with size 1662*2411 
[image]

I want resize it to 706*1009 with keep quality with this command.

```
magick.exe "IMEG0000063B.tif"  -sample  706x1009! -density 300 -quality 100  "1.jpg"
```

**Result**
[image]
but quality of output is very low and i can not read text file in image?

if i use `resize` command all things is ok and keep quality but i want keep quality and resize with `sample` because `sample` is faster than `resize`?

> The "-sample" resize operator is the fastest resize operator,
>   especially in large scale image reduction. In fact it is also even
>   faster than the "-scale" operator (see above).

I use ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16

please help me

Comment: That's kind of like saying "I want to go faster but I don't want to buy a faster car or use any more petrol" - it isn't going to work. Maybe look at other techniques for going faster - like processing images in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you,your means is that can not keep quality with `sample` command? i use parallel . full my query is` magick.exe "IMEG0000063B.tif"  -sample  706x1009! -background White  label:1111111  -append  -depth 8 -limit thread 8 +write "1.jpg" -thumbnail 200x200! -depth 8 -limit thread 8 +write "thumb_1.jpg"  null`

Comment: You can move `-limit thread 8` and `-depth 8` to the start of the command and just set them once as they will stay set. You can also remove the last `+write` and the `null` leaving the output filename at the end. In respect of parallel, I meant that, if you have lots of images to process, your application could process say 4 images at a time to keep the processing time down - rather than processing one image by 4 or 8 threads.

Comment: Is sample that much faster? You should test to confirm on your system; it might be faster on one type of image but not much different on another.